# Where is the Current symbolic link pointing to for JavaVM links?

Tags: java, osx-mountain-lion, symlink

I am using Mountan Lion and I was wondering where exactly **Current** below is pointing at?
It is apparently pointing at **A** do how can I find out where the **A** is pointed to?

```
user:/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions$ ls -l
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   50  5 Sep 09:37 1.6 -> /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   50  5 Sep 09:38 1.6.0 -> /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk
drwxr-xr-x  8 root  wheel  272  3 Sep 13:33 A
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    1 28 Aug 19:13 Current -> A
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   58  5 Sep 10:01 CurrentJDK -> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_21.jdk/Contents
```

Comment: so A is at /? I don't see any directory called A.

Comment: A is in the same directory as Current (/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions)